# Java AES Encryption not decrypting correctly

Tags: java, gzip, aes

I have this test below where I'm trying to verify that my AES encryption/decryption with compression/decompression is working correctly. I have a test for just the encryption/decryption and a test for just the compression/decompression and I know individually they work correctly, but for some reason when I combine them the IV gets screwed up after the decompression. I'm stuck and don't know what else to look for, can anyone offer any suggestions or help? If I need to post more code let me know. I think I included the important stuff.

For context: What I'm trying to do is take some sensitive data, encrypt it with AES, encrypt the AES key with a RSA public key and then compress those two pieces of data so they can be sent over the wire. Then on the other end I want to decompress the data, use a RSA private key to decrypt the AES key and then use that to decrypt the data. If there is another way to accomplish this I'm not locked into writing everything my self. If you suggest a library please only suggest libraries that I can use in a commercial product.

```
@Test
public void testEncryptionDecryptionProcesses() throws SSHException {

    SSHKey key1 = generateKeyPair();

    UnencryptedData data = new UnencryptedData();
    data.setUserName("hardy");
    data.setHashedPassword("somepassword");
    data.setRequest("eat");
    data.setResponse("");
    data.setTimestamp(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()).toString());
    data.setPublicKeyMod(key1.getPublicMod().toString());
    data.setPublicKey(key1.getPublicKey().toString());

    byte[] bytes = encryptAndCompress(data, key1);

    assertTrue(bytes != null);
    assertTrue(bytes.length > 0);

    UnencryptedData decryptedData = decompressAndDecrypt(bytes, key1);
    assertEquals(data.getDataForEncryption(), decryptedData.getDataForEncryption());

}

public static byte[] encryptAndCompress(UnencryptedData data, SSHKey sshKey) {

    byte[] results = null;

    try {
        byte[] aesKey = createKeyForAES(AES_BIT_LENGTH);
        //this should use the servers public key so that only the server can decrypt it
        //gather data, get a digest, encrypt the data
        UnencryptedData digestedData = createDigest(data);
        //encrypt it
        EncryptedData toCompress = encryptDataAES(digestedData, aesKey);
        String encryptedAESKey = encryptKey(sshKey, aesKey);
        toCompress.setEncryptedAESKey(encryptedAESKey);
        //compress it
        byte[] compressed = compressString(toCompress.getDataForCompression());
        //return the compressed and encrypted data.
        results = compressed;
    } catch(SSHException e) {

        Log.e("SSHFunctions.encryption", "Unable to run the encryption/compression process on the data");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {

        Log.e("SSHFunctions.encryption", "Charset not supported");
    } 

    return results;
}

public static UnencryptedData decompressAndDecrypt(byte[] data, SSHKey sshKey) {

    UnencryptedData results = null;

    try {
        //take the data and decompress it, should result in encryptedData|encryptedAESKey
        byte[] decompressed = decompressString(data);
        String decompressedStr = new String(decompressed, CHAR_SET);
        String[] decompressedArr = decompressedStr.split(SPLIT_STRING);
        //using the users private key decrypt the data
        byte[] decryptedKey = decryptKey(sshKey, decompressedArr[1]);
        EncryptedData encryptedData = new EncryptedData();
        encryptedData.setAesEncryptedData(decompressedArr[0].getBytes(CHAR_SET));
        encryptedData.setIV(decompressedArr[2].getBytes(CHAR_SET)); //TODO: this doesn't seem to decompress correctly
        //create a digest from the decrypted data and compare it with the digest that was included.
        UnencryptedData decryptedDate = decryptDataAES(encryptedData, decryptedKey);
        if(validDigest(decryptedDate)) {

            results = decryptedDate;
        }
        //if equal return the data, if not equal return null
    } catch(Exception e) {

        Log.e("SSHFunctions.decryption", "Unable to run the uncompress/decrypt process on the data");
    }

    return results;
}

public static byte[] decompressString(byte[] toDecompress) {

    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(toDecompress);
    byte[] uncompressed;

    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        GZIPInputStream is = new GZIPInputStream(bis);

        byte[] tmp = new byte[256];

        while (true) {

            int r = is.read(tmp);
            if (r < 0) {

                break;
            }
            buffer.write(tmp, 0, r);
        }
        is.close();

        uncompressed = buffer.toByteArray();

        try {
            bis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ;
        }

        try {
            buffer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            ;
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {

        uncompressed = null;
        Log.e("Zipfunctions.decompress", "Unable to decompress");
    }

    return uncompressed;    
}

public static byte[] compressString(byte[] toCompress) {

    byte[] toCompressBytes = toCompress;
    byte[] compressed;

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(toCompressBytes.length);
    try {
        GZIPOutputStream compressor = new GZIPOutputStream(bos);

        compressor.write(toCompressBytes, 0, toCompress.length);
        compressor.close();

        compressed = bos.toByteArray();

        try {
            bos.close();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            ;
        }
    } catch(IOException e) {

        compressed = null;
        Log.e("ZipFunctions.compress", "Unable to compress data");
    }

    return compressed;      
}
```

Comment: Why do you do `RSA(AES_key) + AES(data)`? It doesn't provide extra security, if someone breaks the RSA key, they can read the unprotected AES key and decrypt the data. If you're really dealing with sensitive data, don't be Dave: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25585 (i.e. don't try to implement your own cryptosystem)

Comment: I am not sure if creating a `String` out of binary data is reliable? Have you tried Base64 encoding the compressed data?

Comment: I recommend you to paste only core part of your code instead of your specialized classes. I mean, just try to `encrypt,compress/decompress,decrypt` simple byte array..

Comment: @us2012 - I'm using RSA(AES_key) + AES(data) because I need to send encrypted data and I need to send the AES key to the other party and don't want to send it plain text. Other posts I've read talk about using RSA to encrypt the AES key.

Comment: @Akdeniz - I am trying to encrypt/decrypt and compress/decompress simple byte arrays. The problem is that I need to send the data to the server and I thought converting to a string wouldn't cause problems and would be a simple way to send the data. Is there another way?

Comment: @cdman52 Okay, so it's for performance reasons? That's valid, but as I said - don't think it will provide additional security. Also, `String`s deal with encodings and stuff like that. If you want to send byte arrays, *use* byte arrays.

Comment: @us2012 - Also, I don't want to be "Dave" I'm trying to use the built in libraries instead of creating my own, If you know another way to send data securely I'd love to use that instead, I just need to be sure the data sent is secure.

Comment: @us2012 There is nothing wrong with `RSA(AES_key) + AES(data)` - this is roughly how OpenPGP works. I agree, however, that an existing implementation should be sought, where available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to implement a crypto-system that is similar to [OpenPGP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880). That is, you are wanting to encrypt arbitrary amounts of data with a symmetric key and securely share this key (and the encrypted data) with the recipient(s).

As  a result, I would suggest you consider using the Java OpenPGP libraries [provided by the BouncyCastle team](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/pgdocs1.5on/index.html).

Their license is [very permissive](http://www.bouncycastle.org/licence.html). However, their documentation is infamously poor, so you will need to Google many examples to see how to achieve your goals.

Comment: That sounds exactly like what I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not use string-delimiter to separate parts of byte buffer. It would cause problem if your delimiter character exists in your data.

I suggest you to read about [TLV structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type-length-value)!

Here is a simple implementation of transport data!

```
class TransportData {
private byte[] iv;
private byte[] aesKey;
private byte[] encryptedData;

public TransportData() {
}

public TransportData(byte[] iv, byte[] aesKey, byte[] encryptedData) {
this.iv = iv;
this.aesKey = aesKey;
this.encryptedData = encryptedData;
}

public byte[] encode() throws IOException {
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(baos);
dos.writeInt(iv.length);
dos.write(iv);
dos.writeInt(aesKey.length);
dos.write(aesKey);
dos.writeInt(encryptedData.length);
dos.write(encryptedData);
dos.close();
return baos.toByteArray();
}

public void decode(byte[] buffer) throws IOException {
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(bais);
iv = new byte[dis.readInt()];
dis.read(iv);
aesKey = new byte[dis.readInt()];
dis.read(aesKey);
encryptedData = new byte[dis.readInt()];
dis.read(encryptedData);
dis.close();
}

public byte[] getAesKey() {
return aesKey;
}
public byte[] getEncryptedData() {
return encryptedData;
}
public byte[] getIv() {
return iv;
}
}
```